# PDFium: reading values of form fields?

Tags: forms, text, field, pdfium

How to parse form using PDFium, obtaining values of text fields, button statuses etc ?
I tried this code, but FPDFTextObj_GetText returns empty string.

```
ScopedFPDFTextPage pTextPage (FPDFText_LoadPage(Page));
for (int i = 0;i < FPDFPage_CountObjects(Page); i++)
{ 
    FPDF_PAGEOBJECT pageObj = FPDFPage_GetObject(Page, i);
    auto pageObjType = FPDFPageObj_GetType(pageObj);
    if (pageObjType == FPDF_PAGEOBJ_TEXT)
    {
        auto size =  FPDFTextObj_GetText(pageObj, pTextPage.get(), nullptr, 0);
        std::vector<FPDF_WCHAR> buffer = GetFPDFWideStringBuffer(size);
        size = FPDFTextObj_GetText(pageObj, pTextPage.get(), buffer.data(), size);
    }
    else if (pageObjType == FPDF_PAGEOBJ_FORM)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < FPDFFormObj_CountObjects(pageObj); j++)
        {
            auto formObj = FPDFFormObj_GetObject(pageObj, j);
            auto formObjType = FPDFPageObj_GetType(formObj);
            if (formObjType == FPDF_PAGEOBJ_TEXT)
            {
                auto size =  FPDFTextObj_GetText(pageObj, pTextPage.get(), nullptr, 0);
                std::vector<FPDF_WCHAR> buffer = GetFPDFWideStringBuffer(size);
                size = FPDFTextObj_GetText(pageObj, pTextPage.get(), buffer.data(), size);
            }
    
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

FPDFFormObj_*() refers to an XObjectForm page object which, despite its name including "form", is completely separate from the interactive form (and its fields) embedded into a document. (See PDF reference manual v1.6, section 8.6, which notes the unfortunate ambiguity.)

What you want to do instead is iterate over the *annotations* in the page and look for annotations with annotation type Widget or XFAWidget. Those are the form fields, and you can use the standard FPDFAnnot_* functions to retrieve the content values.